# How does one remove the lines between rows of a mat-table in angular?

Tags: angular, mat-table

Please have a look at my website here:

http://35.232.230.0:81

This shows a mat-table in an angular application. I would like to remove the white lines between the rows of the table. How does one do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   td.mat-cell {
        border-bottom-style: none;
      }
```

Or

```
table-container{
      td.mat-cell {
        border-bottom-style: none;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Mohamed!

Answer (score 3):

mat-cell and mat-header-cell have the borders. just set border none for those elements.

```
.mat-cell, .mat-header-cell {
  border: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are changes in class name for "@angular/material": "^15.2.5"

```
td.mat-mdc-cell{ border: none; }
th.mat-mdc-header-cell{ border: none;}
```